# Website zoom-in zoom-out distorts the content

Tags: html, zooming

I am new to UI design, and I'm trying to create a tabbed layout.

All the tabs are on the center top, and then there are two divs on each other:

1. Blue Div
2. Red Div

---

The problem is with zooming in and out.

- Zoom out misplaces all the tabs (tab F moves to another row).
- Same sort of problem with zoom in: Content moves somewhere else apart from their original positioning

I just want the zooming to work the same as image zooming. The content should not move anywhere.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
<style type="text/css">
body,html {
 height: 100%;
}

div.tabcontents {
 padding: 1%;
 background-color: black;
 color: white;
 height: 80%;
 background-color: blue;
 margin-left: 10%;
 margin-right: 10%;
}

ul.tabs {
 padding: 1% 0;
 font-size: 0;
 margin: 0;
 list-style-type: none;
 text-align: right;
}

ul.tabs li {
 display: inline;
 margin: 0;
 margin-right: 1%; /*distance between tabs*/
 font: normal 14px Verdana;
 padding: 0.5% 4%;
 border: 1px solid white;
 border-bottom-color: black;
 color: white;
}

ul.tabs li a:hover,ul.tabs li:hover,ul.tabs li.activeTab {
 background: black;
 color: white;
}

ul.tabs li a {
 text-decoration: none;
 color: white;
}
</style>
</head>
<body bgcolor="black">
 
  <ul class="tabs" style="margin-right: 19%">
   <li id="admin" class="activeTab"><a>tabA</a></li>
   <li id="admin" class="activeTab"><a>tabB</a></li>
   <li id="admin" class="activeTab"><a>tabC</a></li>
   <li id="admin" class="activeTab"><a>tabD</a></li>
   <li id="admin" class="activeTab"><a>tabE</a></li>
   <li id="admin" class="activeTab"><a>tabF</a></li>

  </ul>
  <div class="tabcontents">
   <div style="height: 100%; background-color: red"></div>
  </div>
 
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Why are you doing *all* values in percentages? That's bound to end up in problems.

Comment: Even if I change the padding and margins in pixels the problem is same. I just want the similar zoomin zoomout support as stackoverflow website. Zoomin and zoomout never displace the content anywhere (only font is reduced or enlarged).

Answer (score 0):

**Try Removing The Padding from the tab list**

```
ul.tabs li {
    display: inline;
    margin: 0;
    margin-right: 1%; /*distance between tabs*/
    font: normal 14px Verdana;
    padding: 0.5% 4%;    /*Remove This*/
    border: 1px solid white;
    border-bottom-color: black;
    color: white;
```

**your new CSS will be looks like**

```
ul.tabs li {
        display: inline;
        margin: 0;
        margin-right: 1%; /*distance between tabs*/
        font: normal 14px Verdana;
        border: 1px solid white;
        border-bottom-color: black;
        color: white;
```

**Also I made the following Changes:**

```
ul.tabs {
            padding: 1% 0;
            font-size: 0;
            margin: 0;
            list-style-type: none;
            text-align: center; /* Text made center*/
        }
```

**Removed the Style from**

```
<ul class="tabs" style="margin-right: 19%">
```

now looks like `<ul class="tabs">`

**The whole code:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
    <title>Insert title here</title>
    <style type="text/css">
        body,html {
            height: 100%;
        }

        div.tabcontents {
            padding: 4%;
            color: white;
            height: 80%;
            background-color: blue;
            margin-left: 10%;
            margin-right: 10%;
        }

        ul.tabs {
            padding: 1% 0;
            font-size: 0;
            margin: 0;
            list-style-type: none;
            text-align: center;
        }

        ul.tabs li {
            position:static;
            max-width: 80%;
            display: inline;
            margin: 3px;
            margin-right: 1%; /*distance between tabs*/
            font: normal 14px Verdana;
            border: 1px solid white;
            border-bottom-color: black;
            color: white;
        }

        ul.tabs li a:hover,ul.tabs li:hover,ul.tabs li.activeTab {
            background: black;
            color: white;
        }

        ul.tabs li a {
            text-decoration: none;
            color: white;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body bgcolor="black">

<ul class="tabs" >
    <li id="admin" class="activeTab"><a>tabA</a></li>
    <li id="admin" class="activeTab"><a>tabB</a></li>
    <li id="admin" class="activeTab"><a>tabC</a></li>
    <li id="admin" class="activeTab"><a>tabD</a></li>
    <li id="admin" class="activeTab"><a>tabE</a></li>
    <li id="admin" class="activeTab"><a>tabF</a></li>

</ul>
<div class="tabcontents">
    <div style="height: 100%; background-color: red"></div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```